# setTimeout not working on safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, settimeout

I have a function that shows a menu when clicking on it, and I want it to disappear after  5 seconds. This is my javascript - it works properly on desktop browser but it doesn't disappear on the mobile ones.

```
$(function() {
    $('#prod_btn').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').next('ul').css('display', 'block');
        setTimeout(hideMenu, 5000);
    });
});

function hideMenu() {
    $('#prod_btn').removeClass('selected').next('ul').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The timeout is firing in safari mobile for me when I put an alert() in the hideMenu() function. Is it working for you?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show anything, it seems that it don't fire the function...

Comment: What versions are you using of jquery, safari, etc?  It works for me with jquery 1.6.4 and iOS 4.3 on the simulator.  Are you getting errors?

Comment: I tried on iPhone 4 and iPad 2 with iOS 5, and on iPhone 3GS with 4.3 and it still not works, I'm using jquery 1.6.2

Comment: I have no errors, just don't do anything, neither the alert message...

Comment: I also tried with jquery 1.7 from google apis whitout any change

Answer (score 8):

I've just had the same problem. My code is running great in any browser on my Mac, but on iOs devices it doesn't work.

I use ".bind(this)" on my timeout function and that is what is causing the problem for me.
When I extend the function object with ".bind" in my script it works like a charm.

My code is something like this:

```
searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
...
}.bind(this),250);
```

For this to work on iOs devices I (like mentioned above) just added this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(parent) {
    var f = this;
    var args = [];

    for (var a = 1; a < arguments.length; a++) {
        args[args.length] = arguments[a];
    }

    var temp = function() {
        return f.apply(parent, args);
    }

    return(temp);
}
```

I don't see any .bind on your setTimeout, but for others with the same problem this may be the issue. That's why I'm posting :-)

Comment: This is a major issue. I just went through trying to debug 20k lines trying to figure out why it was working in iOS 6 and not iOS 5. Thanks!!!

Comment: Using your first example. This works on iOS 9.2! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I moved your example to a jsbin, and it's working on my iphone 4.

Please test it out going here from your devices: http://jsbin.com/asihac/5

You can see the code here http://jsbin.com/asihac/5/edit

The example is using jQuery - latest and I only added the required css class.

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't apply to your code, but a common problem with long-running scripts failing on iOS devices is that MobileSafari kills a javascript thread after 10 seconds have elapsed. you *should* be able to use setTimeout and/or setInterval to work around this, or you can avoid it by making a shortcut to it and thereby running it as an app. see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2298038, particularly the comments by Dane Harrigan.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind also that any setTimeout function is actually likely fire while DOM elements are rendering if the delay is set to a value too short. While that might seem obvious, it can be easily confused with no method firing whatsoever. A good way to test is to have an alert prompt run.

```
window.onLoad(alert("hey!"));
```

Then check to see if your function fires after.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.

The problem arose on iOS mobile devices running the Safari browser.

Based on this answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768617
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033979/5646020

I opted for an alternative approach by switching from setTimeout to setInterval. However, this solution is slightly more complex as it requires calling clearInterval once the desired time has elapsed.