# How do browsers pause/change Javascript when tab or window is not active?

Tags: javascript, browser

Background: I'm doing some user interface tests that need to detect if people are paying attention or not. But, this question is **not** about [the page visibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/586086).

Specifically, I would like to know how my Javascript code will be affected if the current tab is not active, or the browser window is not active, in different browsers. I've dug up the following so far:

- [ios 5 pauses javascript when tab is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7977170/586086)
- [`setInterval` and `setTimeout` delay is reduced when tabs are not active](http://pivotallabs.com/chrome-and-firefox-throttle-settimeout-setinterval-in-inactive-tabs/) - seems like this just started appearing recently and can mess up Jasmine unit tests, around other things.
- `requestAnimationFrame` is slowed when tab is not active (reasonable, can't think of why this would affect anyone too much)

I have the following questions:

- Other than mobile browsers, do desktop browsers ever pause JS execution when a tab is not active? When and which browsers?
- Which browsers reduce the `setInterval` repeat? Is it just reduced to a limit or by a percentage? For example, if I have a 10ms repeat versus a 5000ms repeat, how will each be affected?
- Do these changes happen if the *window* is out of focus, as opposed to just the tab? (I imagine it would be harder to detect, as it requires the OS API.)
- Are there any other effects that would not be observed in an active tab? Could they mess things up that would otherwise execute correctly (i.e. the aforementioned Jasmine tests)?

Comment: If they are paused, sites like Facebook wouldn't receive any chat messages on background tabs.

Comment: +1 This doesn't happen anywhere, it wouldn't surprise me if (some) browsers lessoned the priority of setInterval, but I doubt it would make much difference.

Comment: Yeah there's no pausing, but I do remember reading that the `setInterval`/`setTimeout` times under 1000ms are changed to 1000ms when the tab/window is blurred

Comment: @Ian can you find a reliable source for that?

Comment: @AndrewMao I wish I could. Haha I'm sorry, I think it's just a browser implementation...it's definitely not part of any standard.

Comment: @lan  `setInterval`/`setTimeout` times under 1000ms are changed to 1000ms when the tab/window is blurred. Not clear what you tried to convey

Comment: +1 Great question.  It would be good to see a side by side comparison of browser behaviours, as I believe the clamping behaviour when tabs are not active is not part of any standard.

Comment: i would suspect each browser does it different. onky way to find out is to check sources and or ask on the forums for every browser. Also, there's a chance this behavior changes a bit depending on the browser version.

Comment: i can only get about 200 executions per second on defered when the tab is active, 1 per sec on inactive

Answer (score 218, accepted):

### Test One

I have written a test specifically for this purpose:
[Frame Rate Distribution: setInterval vs requestAnimationFrame](http://laucheukhim.github.io/frame-rate-distribution/)

<sup>Note: This test is quite CPU intensive. `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported by IE 9- and Opera 12-.</sup>

The test logs the actual time it takes for a `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` to run in different browsers, and gives you the results in the form of a distribution. You can change the number of milliseconds for `setInterval` to see how it runs under different settings. `setTimeout` works similarly to a `setInterval` with respect to delays. `requestAnimationFrame` generally defaults to the 60fps depending on the browser. To see what happens when you switch to a different tab or have an inactive window, simply open the page, switch to a different tab and wait for a while. It will continue to log the actual time it takes for these functions in an inactive tab.

### Test Two

Another way to test it is to log the timestamp repeatedly with `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` and view it in a detached console. You can see how frequently it is updated (or if it is ever updated) when you make the tab or window inactive.

- [Test for `setInterval`](http://jsfiddle.net/laucheukhim/Aev79/)
- [Test for `requestAnimationFrame`](http://jsfiddle.net/laucheukhim/WfdnM/1/)

### Results

**Chrome**
Chrome limits the minimum interval of `setInterval` to around 1000ms when the tab is inactive. If the interval is higher than 1000ms, it will run at the specified interval. It does not matter if the window is out of focus, the interval is limited only when you switch to a different tab. `requestAnimationFrame` is paused when the tab is inactive.

```
// Provides control over the minimum timer interval for background tabs.
const double kBackgroundTabTimerInterval = 1.0;
```

<sup>https://codereview.chromium.org/6546021/patch/1001/2001</sup>

**Firefox**
Similar to Chrome, Firefox limits the minimum interval of `setInterval` to around 1000ms when the tab (not the window) is inactive. However, `requestAnimationFrame` runs exponentially slower when the tab is inactive, with each frame taking 1s, 2s, 4s, 8s and so on.

```
// The default shortest interval/timeout we permit
#define DEFAULT_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE 4 // 4ms
#define DEFAULT_MIN_BACKGROUND_TIMEOUT_VALUE 1000 // 1000ms
```

<sup>https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/file/0bf1cadfb004/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#l296</sup>

**Internet Explorer**
IE does not limit the delay in `setInterval` when the tab is inactive, but it pauses `requestAnimationFrame` in inactive tabs. It does not matter whether the window is out of focus or not.

**Edge**
Starting from Edge 14, `setInterval` is capped at 1000ms in inactive tabs. `requestAnimationFrame` is always paused in inactive tabs.

**Safari**
Just like Chrome, Safari caps `setInterval` at 1000ms when the tab is inactive. `requestAnimationFrame` is paused as well.

**Opera**
Since the adoption of the Webkit engine, Opera exhibits the same behavior as Chrome. `setInterval` is capped at 1000ms and `requestAnimationFrame` is paused when the tab is inactive.

### Summary

Repeating intervals for inactive tabs:

```
           setInterval     requestAnimationFrame
Chrome
9-         not affected    not supported
10         not affected    paused
11+        >=1000ms        paused

Firefox
3-         not affected    not supported
4          not affected    1s
5+         >=1000ms        2ns (n = number of frames since inactivity)

IE
9-         not affected    not supported
10+        not affected    paused

Edge
13-        not affected    paused
14+        >=1000ms        paused

Safari
5-         not affected    not supported
6          not affected    paused
7+         >=1000ms        paused

Opera
12-        not affected    not supported
15+        >=1000ms        paused
```

Comment: Great answer. Any other possible known differences for functions other than `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: @AndrewMao Not that I am aware of. I came across this issue when I was working on a library to reliably detect if JS reenabled with `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`. The thing I know about is that `setTimeout` behaves similarly to `setInterval`, in that they both have the same minimum background interval in Firefox and Chrome, and no apparent limit in other browsers.

Comment: The Firefox setInterval minimum value can apparently be changed by opening the url `about:config` in the browser and changing the `dom.min_background_timeout_value` value to something else than 1000.

Comment: can i use this to reload page every 5 seconds when browser is minimized ?, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376157/javascript-reload-page-every-5-seconds-when-browser-is-minimized) is my question.

Comment: Note that chrome does not pause/reduce the rate at which `requestAnimationFrame` is called if the user simply switches application (Alt+Tab out of Chrome). As long as the tab is active in Chrome the "frame rate" is more or less constant.

Comment: @JonasBerlin awesome! This has an immediate effect without browser restart.

Answer (score 12):

What I observed : on inactive tabs in **Chrome**, all your `setTimeout` (must be the same for `setInterval`) waiting less than *1000ms* are rounded to *1000ms*. I think longer timeouts are not modified.

Seems to be the behavior since **Chrome 11** and **Firefox 5.0** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Inactive_tabs

Furthermore, I don't think it behaves this way when the whole window is inactive (but it seems quite easy to investigate).

Comment: jQuery's `focus` and `blur` events seem to detect both tab and window switches, so it could conceivably work both ways. But I wonder how the window detects if it's actually visible or not.

Comment: Actually it has no connection with **jQuery** or **Javascript** as it is internal browser implementation.

Comment: Can you confirm this now in late 2016?

Answer (score 1):

A newer answer to complement these: on chrome 78.0.3904.108 I notice **all** of these timeouts (not just those below 1000ms) taking a bit longer than expected when I move to a different tab, and then come back. The behaviour I am seeing is more correctly described as *"All timeouts on inactive tabs may be delayed by some additional amount, to a maximum of 1000ms."* Try running the following and switching to another tab!

```js
let timeouts = [ 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 10000 ];

let minExcess = document.getElementsByClassName('minExcess')[0];

timeouts.forEach(ms => {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName(`t${ms}`)[0];
  let cnt = 0;
  
  let lastMs = +new Date();
  let f = () => {
    let curMs = +new Date();
    let disp = document.createElement('p');
    let net = curMs - lastMs;
    lastMs = curMs;
        
    setTimeout(f, ms);
    if (minExcess.value && (net - ms) < parseInt(minExcess.value)) return;
    
    disp.innerText = `${net},`;
    elem.appendChild(disp);
    if (++cnt > 10) elem.firstElementChild.remove();
    
  };
  setTimeout(f, ms);
  
});
```

```css
body { font-size: 80%; }
div {
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
p { margin: 0; }
div > p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
input { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
.t500:before { display: block; content: '500ms'; font-weight: bold; }
.t1000:before { display: block; content: '1000ms'; font-weight: bold; }
.t2000:before { display: block; content: '2000ms'; font-weight: bold; }
.t3000:before { display: block; content: '3000ms'; font-weight: bold; }
.t10000:before { display: block; content: '10000ms'; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p>Ignore any values delayed by less than this amount:</p>
<input type="text" class="minExcess" value="200" pattern="^[0-9]*$"/>
<div class="timeout t500"></div>
<div class="timeout t1000"></div>
<div class="timeout t2000"></div>
<div class="timeout t3000"></div>
<div class="timeout t10000"></div>
```