# Why does setInterval() stop too early in this code?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
<div class="wait">Wait</div>
<div class="waitDownloadLink"></div>

$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      var secondNormal = 40;
                      var refreshIntervalId;
                      refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
                          secondNormal -= 1;
                          $(".wait").text(secondNormal);

                      }, 1000); 
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                          $(".waitDownloadLink").text("Click me to download");
                      }, secondNormal * 1000);




                  });
```

When I start running the code and stay on the webpage, the code seems too work perfectly (or nearly). However, when I surf on other webpage right after I started the code, the timer is stuck between 12 - 18 second and then stops running. Why does this happen? And is there any solution to solve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/s1zf18co/

Comment: seems to work fine for me..

Comment: What browser are you using @Joshua? I'm unable to replicate in Chrome.

Comment: It works for me only if I stay on the webpage...

Comment: @James G. I am using chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot seem to replicate the bug, however I believe that using the Date object may fix it:

```
var getDateTimeInSeconds = function() {
  return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOfSeconds = 40;
  var countFrom = getDateTimeInSeconds();
  var countTo = countFrom + numOfSeconds;

  var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var secondsLeft = countTo - getDateTimeInSeconds();
    if (secondsLeft < 0) {
      $(".wait").text(0);
      $(".waitDownloadLink").text("Click me to download");
      clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    } else {
      $(".wait").text(secondsLeft);
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s1zf18co/1/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers typically pause or reduce thread priority for Javascript running in tabs that aren't visible. My guess is that it's a power saving measure for laptops and other things, but they all have done this for years now. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871942/how-do-browsers-pause-change-javascript-when-tab-or-window-is-not-active) has an incredibly thorough investigation into the issue.

The solution is to use web workers which don't get paused. See [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for more information.

Comment: This is what I would assume as well, but I can't replicate it using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

there is one working solution, try this and c if it is good enough, it is ok with leaving page problem, edit on end condition.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var secondNormal = 40;

    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if(secondNormal >0) {
                secondNormal -= 1;
            }
        }, 1000)

        $(".wait").text(secondNormal);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Mordred's answer, in this case you may try using JS `Date` object to correctly estimate time. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927432/2109322).