# Execute javascript on a specific Google Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard-maestro

I'm running this javascript to click a link through my Chrome browser

```
document.getElementById('extractResults').click();
```

It's clicking fine, until I navigate away from the browser tab or window. Any insights into how to execute the action even after I've navigated away from the tab?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a bit more details about what you are trying to do?  If you are fine this happening 'automatically in the background', I would suggest you look at `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you're "running this javascript"... are you using `setInterval()` or something similar?

You might do a google search for "javascript background tabs" -- there are a lot of related issues (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871942/how-do-browsers-pause-change-javascript-when-tab-or-window-is-not-active)) and the bottom line seems to be that modern browsers are saving CPU (etc) by not running everything when in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I'm running the script in a macro using Keyboard Maestro.