# call javascript function with c# methods in razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to reload a page every 10 seconds ,  using Cache Scheduler method mentioned [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/),

I just want call a `JavaScript` function to reload current page when `Cache` is removed. But for some reason  basic JavaScript doesn't work.

**Razor View:**

```
@{

AddTask("CheckStatus", 10); // reload page every 10 seconds

@functions
{

private static System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

public void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
OnCacheRemove = new System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
        
}


public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v,
System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
        
 PrintStatus();

}


}


}


@helper PrintStatus()
{
 
 var msg = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 alert('Status is open!');</script>";

 @Html.Raw(msg)

}
```

What am i doing wrong ? Or Is there any alternate way to return `Javascript` to reload page using server side code.

**Note:** I am not using `Javascript` `set interval` because `Chrome` has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376157/javascript-reload-page-every-5-seconds-when-browser-is-minimized) when the browser is minimized, so i prefer server side code to reload page every x seconds.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you need to use this exact way? Why don't you call the C# methods by ajax instead every x seconds and in `success` do something. Cleaner than this way because at the moment you are mixing scripts and C# functions into the view which is hard to maintain.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350446/how-to-schedule-ajax-calls-every-n-seconds

Edit: Ah, success wouldn't work for what you want, I don't know a way of callback from cache expire.

Comment: @Martin Mazza Dawson I am not using `Javascript` `set interval` because `Chrome` has [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376157/javascript-reload-page-every-5-seconds-when-browser-is-minimized) when the browser is minimized, i have updated the post check my Notes. But is there way to call JS function ?

Comment: It's probably worth thinking about ***why*** chrome doesn't run JS when minimized. What's the point? Are you trying to write a webpage that will drain the user's battery without them realising? Be polite. Work within the sensible boundaries that browser manufacturers put in place. Why can't you just reload the page when it regains focus?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a repackaged version of [your old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376157/javascript-reload-page-every-5-seconds-when-browser-is-minimized)

Comment: @spender , I know chrome does it to increase performance but Our scenario is that user opens the browser or keep minimized  , so the scheduler should do the job when not in focus, This is my 3rd question , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420763/quartz-net-schedule-to-reload-asp-mvc-action-method-every-30-seconds) is one more using Quartz scheduler , still no solutions.

Comment: @spender Inside my view I tried using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/");` but it doesnt works because `HttpContext` is null, so is there a way to fake make `HttpContext` and to  force redirection to some action method ? Can i make redirect inside a view ?

Answer (score 0):

The cache scheduler is server-side piece of code. It is useless on client. The way this would fire is only if by some miracle the CacheRemoveItem will fire when you're rendering the view.

If I were you I'd create some AJAX service and periodically call it from javascript using setInterval.

Comment: I am not using `Javascript` `set interval` because `Chrome` has [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376157/javascript-reload-page-every-5-seconds-when-browser-is-minimized) when the browser is minimized, so i prefer server side code to reload page every x seconds. But is there way to call JS function somehow ?

Comment: @stom - there is no way web server can force reload of page (short of politely asking client to do so in html he sends out - either via meta or via javascript as noted in your question).

Comment: Ok, my razor view  is mix of c# method But is there way to call JS function somehow or `return JavaScript`  ?

Comment: @stom - stop for a minute and think about it - user can close a browser or navigate to some other page, etc. Html is stateless - once server is done rendering html it is no more communicating with client

Comment: I know that, actually here user keeps the page open or some time minimized , so any how cache should work right ?

Comment: Inside my view I tried using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/");` but it doesnt works because `HttpContext` is null, so is there a way to fake make `HttpContext` and to  force redirection to some action method ?