# Ajax request while window is not focused

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way to keep an ajax request fire every 5 seconds even if the browser tab is not focused ?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871942/how-do-browsers-pause-change-javascript-when-tab-or-window-is-not-active

Comment: So are you using setTimeout or setInterval?