# Javascript: setInterval pausing and skipping while tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, setinterval

If setInterval's interval is 10 milliseconds, then it will pause if the tab is inactive, but if it is set to 1 second, then it doesn't pause and keeps counting when the tab is inactive.
Here are some examples:

1 second -

```js
num = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
  num = num + 1;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = num;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="counter">0</span>
</body>
```

10 milliseconds -

```js
num = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
  num = num + 1;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = num;
}, 10);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="counter">0</span>
</body>
```

It appears to skip 80 numbers in its counting on the second one. Why is this? This happens in the snippet and if you have made it yourself, i.e. as a file on your computer.

Is this to do with my computer's processing power in particular, or its memory, or what? I am very confused about this, so any answers would be appreciated.

So, just to reiterate, my questions are:

1) Why is setInterval pausing?

2) Why has it skipped 80 or so numbers when it pauses and then starts again?

3) Why is this only for shorter time intervals?

Comment: Works fine for me. Both counters start at 1 and continue seamlessly the count. (It's hard to spot it at the second one, but it seems to do good)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do browsers pause/change Javascript when tab or window is not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871942/how-do-browsers-pause-change-javascript-when-tab-or-window-is-not-active)