# Web page timeout and refresh is not working

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I have a web page template on django.
In this template i have two controls. I am waiting the page to be forwarded to another page after a certain time passed.

One is meta :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900;{% url 'list-attendance' %}"/>
```

and second one is script :

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
window.location.href = "{% url 'list-attendance' %}";
},610000);
</script>
```

If i open one page on browser it works. And redirects to list-attendance url.
But if i open same page in two tabs on same browser, one of the pages redirect other one stucks and does not redirect.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871942/how-do-browsers-pause-change-javascript-when-tab-or-window-is-not-active). It may relate to your case.

Comment: it seems javascript is not working in notactive tabs :(