# settimeout issue on iOS devices

Tags: angularjs, mobile-safari, settimeout

The below timeout function is not working on iOS devices. 
Is `settimeout` function does not work on iOS devices?
Is there something missing in below code?

```
_timeoutService: ng.ITimeoutService



this._timeoutService(1200, true).then(() => {
          //below statement does not have any effect on iOS devices
          // enable my angular material control
          // set some text in an angular material input element
           this.supportEmailCtrlDisabled = false;
        });
```

I came across this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10991974/5252545. Looks like a similar issue. But not sure -
 1. If this solves my issue?
 2. what a 'bind' method is?
 3. How to write the method in typescript?

Comment: How can I close this question?

Answer (score 1):

> //below statement does not have any effect on iOS devices

Suspect the issue is higher up the call chain. The function is possibly called from outside `$apply` which means the `then` doesn't fire.

## Possible fix

```
this._timeoutService(1200, true).then(() => {
          //below statement does not have any effect on iOS devices
          // enable my angular material control
          // set some text in an angular material input element
           this.supportEmailCtrlDisabled = false;
           $scope.$apply()
        });
```

Comment: the statement does execute but have no effect.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout, I thought the 2nd parameter true runs the apply

Comment: @LearnForever if the statement does run but has no effect then put the apply into the `.then`. I've updated the answer