# How to manipulate webcam video before streaming over WebRTC even when the tab is inactive?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have been through many similar QnAs and articles. Overall it seems the only solution is to connect the `userMedia` stream to `video` then use a timer function to take snapshot from the `video` and put it on a `canvas`. Now manipulate the stuff on `canvas` and stream that.

The problem is the timer function. If I use `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` then the video stream becomes choppy or completely stops if the user moves away from the tab. I somehow worked around that using Web worker (using below code).

```
      (function () {
        let blob = new Blob([`
        onmessage = function(oEvent) {
          setTimeout(() => postMessage('tick'), oEvent[1]);
        };
        `],{type: 'text/javascript'});
        window.myTimeout = function (cb, t) {
          const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
          worker.onmessage = function(oEvent) {
            cb();
            worker.terminate();
          };
          worker.postMessage(['start', t]);
        };
      }());
```

However this works well on Chrome but on Safari (OSX) this fails completely. Safari seems to pause the JS engine completely. This issue does not happen if I stream `userMedia` directly.

Comment: Seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768173/safari-javascript-settimeout-stops-when-minimized

Comment: Timers get clamped when the tab is not in focus.
You might want to try the new (still in origin trial) breakout box API described in https://web.dev/mediastreamtrack-insertable-media-processing/